# C# How to Insert data from text boxes to datagridview and then save the datagridview data into database?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, visual-studio-code

I am working on Desktop Application and want to insert data from text boxes to Datagridview and then save the Datagridview data into database with multiple rows can any one help me how can i do this with simple/advance and smooth way...

[Here is the i have tried in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxOot.png)

```
private void AddRowToDataGridviewUsingTextboxes() {
        table.Columns.Add("Order Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Product Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
        table.Columns.Add("Product Name", typeof(string));

        DataGridViewOrderProduct.DataSource = table;

    }


 private void BtnAddProductToDataGridview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(txtOrderCode.Text,ProductCodeComboBox.SelectedItem, txtQuantity.Text, txtPrice.Text, txtProductName.Text, PaymentComboBox.SelectedItem,ShipmentComboBox.SelectedItem,txtCustomerName.Text,txtCAddress.Text, txtCPhone.Text, CountryComboBox.SelectedItem );
        DataGridViewOrderProduct.DataSource = table;
    }
```

[And Here is the Form on where the problem to be resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVfff.png)

Comment: Please check the images in the query as i mentioned code i tried and form where to work on

Comment: I think you should convet the price to decimal before including it in the rows.add method. Other than that: What happens. - Also: it is strongly frowned upon to add code as images. Do not do that! - also always add a full decription of what goes wrong and/or what specific question you have. As it stands the question is much to broad!

Comment: I converted already into decimal that is not the matter

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnAdd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name_Column1 = txtUomtyp.Text;
        string Name_Column2 = txtUomDesc.Text;
        string[] row = { Column1, Column2};
        DatGridView.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Providing code is good but it would be nice if you can explain why and how your code works. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23590287)